# Post-upgrade command has not been added to the allowed list in allowedPostUpgradeCommands in Renovate

Tags: renovate

I am using self hosted renovate and want to use `postUpgradeTasks` to run an update script only one the name of renovate branch matches an specific branch name pattern (upgrade/template-*), for other case the update script need not be called. I am using an if condition but getting error message

> Post-upgrade command 'if ["{{{branchName}}}" == "upgrade/template-*"];
> then ./bootstrap/.helper/upgrade.sh {{{newVersion}}} {{{branchName}}};
> fi' has not been added to the allowed list in
> allowedPostUpgradeCommands

My renoavte.json file looks like this and `allowedPostUpgradeCommands` allows everything. I am not getting a clue why this error pops up all the time.

`renovate.json` -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [],
  "branchPrefix": "upgrade/",
  "regexManagers": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["^VERSION$"],
      "matchStrings": [
        "(?<currentValue>.*)"
      ],
      "datasourceTemplate": "gitlab-releases",
      "depNameTemplate": "lmn/pqr/template",
      "registryUrlTemplate": "https://abc.xyz.com"
    }
  ],
  "forkProcessing": "enabled",
  "allowedPostUpgradeCommands": [".*"],
  "postUpgradeTasks": {
    "commands": ["if [\"{{{branchName}}}\" == \"upgrade/template-*\"]; then ./bootstrap/.helper/upgrade.sh {{{newVersion}}} {{{branchName}}}; fi"],
    "executionMode": "branch",
    "fileFilters": ["**/*", "**/.*"]
  },
  "enabledManagers": ["regex", "flux"],
  "flux": {
    "fileMatch": [
      "(^|/)flux-system/(?:.+/)?gotk-components\\.(ya?ml)$",
      "(^|/)infrastructure/.*?/.*\\.ya?ml$",
      "(^|/)bootstrap/crossplane/.*?/.*\\.ya?ml$"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was though I was explicitly allowing all command by  `"allowedPostUpgradeCommands": [".*"]`
This was a misconception for the case of self hosted agent. This configuration must be done at global renovate config and not at renovate.json level.